# Как извлечь picturebox из control?

Tags: c#, windows, controls, picturebox

Ситуация такая, программа считает решение курсовой работы, делает массив картинок-формул для последующей вставки в ворд. На окне отображается столько картинок, сколько получилось формул, в зависимости от исходных данных.

```
public void ShowDialog(Image[] formules)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(Image formula in formules)
    {
        PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
        picture.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
        picture.Location = new Point(0, i * 90);
        picture.Size = formula.Size;
        picture.BackgroundImage = formula;
        panel1.Controls.Add(picture);
        i++;
    }
    ShowDialog();
}
```

Для всех них одно контекстное меню. Вопрос в том, как извлечь картинку для буфера обмена?

Comment: winforms или wpf?

Comment: winforms, но я походу уже разобрался как это сделать) попробую через табиндекс панели

Comment: Похожие вопросы идут косяками... Вчера дал [ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33662910/5045688) на похожий вопрос.

Comment: Да, в моем случае ваше решение гораздо лучше табиндекса) еще не до конца разобрался с синтаксисом шарпа

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение проблемы:

```
void contextMenuStrip1_Click(object sender, EventHandler e)
{
       PictureBox picture = (PictureBox)contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl;
       Clipboard.SetImage(picture.Image);
}
```

вот так просто все оказалось